# How to get passwords from Opera Password manager?

Tags: browser, opera, password-management

How I get my passwords from Password manager at Opera?

Is there easy solution? I mean like firefox style.

Comment: What is the Firefox style?

Answer (score 2):

[Reveal Remembered Hidden Password In Opera](http://www.technixupdate.com/reveal-remembered-hidden-password-in-opera-internet-explorer-firefox-google-chrome/) (and others).
Its a short javascript code that will skip the asterisks.
Quite a humbling experience...

Here is one of the scripts with indentation for study,

```
javascript:(
 function()
 {
  var F,j,f,i;
  s="";
  F=document.forms;
  for(j=0;j<F.length;++j)
   {
    f=F[j];
    for(i=0;i<f.length;++i)
    {
      if(f[i].type.toLowerCase()=="password")
      s+=f[i].value+"\n";
    }
   }
   if(s)
     alert("Passwords in forms on thispage:\n\n"+s);
   else
     alert("There are no passwords in forms on this page.");
 }) ();
```

Answer (score 1):

[**WebBrowserPassView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html) by NirSoft allows this. It supports Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

> WebBrowserPassView is a password recovery tool that reveals the
>   passwords stored by the following Web browsers: Internet Explorer
>   (Version 4.0 - 10.0), Mozilla Firefox (All Versions), Google Chrome,
>   Safari, and Opera. This tool can be used to recover your
>   lost/forgotten password of any Website, including popular Web sites,
>   like Facebook, Yahoo, Google, and GMail, as long as the password is
>   stored by your Web Browser.
>
> After retrieving your lost passwords, you can save them into
>   text/html/csv/xml file, by using the 'Save Selected Items' option
>   (Ctrl+S).
>
> [image: WebBrowserPassView screenshot]